# Twitter Product Preview on Tweets

Tags: html, web-development, twitter, rich-snippets

I just saw that twitter can also preview the products as it is on below Tweet:

http://twitter.com/#!/gillcleeren/status/131640082397528065

In this case, it is an Amazon product.

I was wondering how we can enable this for our website? Do we have control over this or Twitter chooses web sites for this feature which they want?

Comment: Related question: [How Does Amazon have so much information in a tweet?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32703/how-does-amazon-have-so-much-information-in-a-tweet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible yet since what you want to do is exactly what [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards) will soon provide:

[image]

It isn't available for every one at the moment but will be available in the future. Right now, you can anticipate the release of Twitter Cards by adding some meta to your html like:

```html
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:description content="Hotel description">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="My Hotel">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://myhotel.com/photo_thumbnail.png">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="http://myhotel.com">
```

And then wait for the availability.

Answer (score 4):

The word for what they are doing is *transclusion*. The method they are using is OEmbed (details [here](http://dashes.com/anil/2010/09/twitter-transclusion-and-trust.html)). According to [twitter though](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/398)

> Sorry, we're not offering a path to inclusion at this time.

Inclusion means inclusion on a whitelist of OEmbed providers.

What gets shown below the tweet depends on the other website - it could be a picture, or "media" which varies. For example, Foursquare show a map; as you've mentioned, Amazon shows selected parts of the page.

Answer (score 3):

This is determined by Twitter, presumably using whatever services/sites they see as most popular or desirable. Also note that the services previewed are referred to as "partnerships," so it seems likely there's actually a formal relationship involved and not just some metadata on your end, for example. The feature was mentioned in an [early blog post](http://blog.twitter.com/2010/09/better-twitter.html) around the launch of "NewTwitter" and another in which they [announced](http://blog.twitter.com/2010/12/now-playing-on-newtwitter-embedded.html) the addition of a bunch more services.

Answer (score 0):

What CMS are you using? I know it also works with WordPress, even if your not hosted on WordPress.org or .com, but I've had mixed results, such as, if you post different blog entries, all of the links will preview your most recent post.

Do you just want to preview your site or media as well? Because Twitter has partnerships with YouTube etc.

Comment: What I want is to view some metadata info about the Hotel and the small main picture of the hotel when someone tweets by linking the hotel's web page url.