# How Does Amazon have so much information in a tweet?

Tags: twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Twitter Product Preview on Tweets](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21508/twitter-product-preview-on-tweets)

So I just saw the tweet below and was wondering, how does amazon get the extra information into the tweet?

[image: amazon tweet]

Comment: Flagging for move; likely belongs at webapps.se.

Comment: @Su' The question I flagged it as duplicate with specifically mentions Amazon. For some reason the tweet it linked to doesn't display product data any more, and we have no screenshot. I think "it's transclusion" doesn't quite answer this question, so I'll add more to the answer there.

Comment: @paulmorriss Erm, yeah. You'll have seen by now I deleted that comment. I glossed some stuff. Twitter seem determined to complicate this. (Note j0k's answer beyond even that.) Still, I'd assume there has to be *some* difference, with there being a good year and a half between the two announcements. More digging needed, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

That's an [expanded tweet](http://blog.twitter.com/2012/06/experience-more-with-expanded-tweets.html). They have partnerships with various companies to display more detailed information from them. The *actual* update is still just the bit above from Ben and stops at the reply, favorite, etc. buttons. The stuff below is injected by Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

This is also related to [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards) which is available for only few web sites at the moment.

The goal is to have expanded tweet from trusted sites to give a better user experience (à la Facebook).